# start putty session when u get a mail with particular subject line in outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, putty

I want my putty session with auto-login(username and password) to start every time i receive a mail with particular keywords in subject line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that basic information its not that easy to give you a propper solution as there isn´t that much infos given by you.

However as an option you could build something via AutoIt. You might monitor your Outlook inbox via AutoIt and once a propper string appears you might wish to trigger some actions (for example running putty).

However monitoring Outlook isn´t the best option here. I really would directly monitor the emails which comes in (e.g. via POP3 / IMAP) and based on that you can trigger some actions. Additional you might wish to build something based on the Outlook API. But as said you didn´t specify infos in your current version from your question I´m not sure if the Outlook API is something you are looking into.